# Error when trying import Bottle-powered web app on Apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, odoo, wsgi, bottle

I am created an api for OpenERP using bottle and when i try to configure wsgi with apache.

While importing in apache server log it shows

ImportError: No module named api

I checked for current directory it prints cwd and the import file is in same directory still it shows error

Here i uploaded my code for wsgi

```
   import os 
   os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
   import bottle
   print os.getcwd()
   import api as application
   application = bottle.defaut_app()
```

Comment: There's a (different) bug in your code: you import api as "application", but then you use "application" as the name of a new variable.  Why not just `import api`?

Comment: i just try to import it as obj but import api also not working

Comment: Still need a hand? Or solved?

Answer (score 1):

What is your `sys.path`?

It must include the *directory* of your `.py` file, not the file name itself. E.g.,

```
sys.path.append('/var/www/api')
# and then, to see its new value:
print sys.path.append
```

Also note how I printed the value of sys.path there; the way you did it in one of your comments (printing the return value from `append`) is incorrect.

Comment: now it prints correctly thanks man i will test the whole api and put result here

Comment: Cool, happy it helped.  If this solved the `ImportError` problem in your question, please consider accepting my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think i had a similar problem and I ended up doing this in my wsgi:

```
import sys
import os
import bottle

sys.path.append('%path to module%')

import %modulename%


application = bottle.default_app()
```

In your py you have to import:

```
from bottle import default_app
```

for this to work.

Comment: Yes. You see I first add the folder with the directory to sys.path. This way I can be sure it'll be found. Then I import it and it is found. Have you tried it ?

Comment: when i print sys path it is says none app = sys.path.append('/var/www/api/api.py')
print app